# Is it acceptable to ask (and answer) a question asking for a real life counterpart of a place seen in an anime?

Tags: discussion, questions, acceptable-questions

I want to ask a question which goes like this:

> What are the places in Love Live that are real places in Japan? How do I go there?

I already have an answer (3 places) to this question, and I am planning on marking it Community Wiki so that everyone can update its content.

Is this kind of question acceptable? Should I ask this question?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, these questions are currently acceptable,

Seeing as you are asking with the intent to visit, you should use the [tourism](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tourism) tag.

Here are some examples of existing questions:

[Is Toyosato Elementary School open to visitors?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/is-toyosato-elementary-school-open-to-visitors)

[Which mountain did they try to climb over?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27516/which-mountain-did-they-try-to-climb-over/27803#27803)

[What are the real world locations for the Districts mentioned in From the New World?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26696/what-are-the-real-world-locations-for-the-districts-mentioned-in-from-the-new-wo)

and one more specific to your question
[The real world location of Akiba Dome](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28864/the-real-world-location-of-akiba-dome)

---

The only thing I would be careful about is how **broad your question is** - Does Love Live take place in a vast number of locations? If it's too large, it might be out of scope for an answerer and potentially closed.

Something like "Are the locations where the group played real-life locations" would be a more appropriate question.

Comment: It does take place in many locations. However the purpose of why I want to ask the question (and also the reason why I want to make it Community Wiki) is to make it the 'canonical' and one-stop post for Love Live real locations. I was also planning on linking that Q&A to the post I am planning to make.

Comment: @ToshinoKyouko so I'm guessing that if I posted such a question, it would be closed as too broad?

Comment: @Keale probably, unless you can reduce it

Comment: @ToshinoKyouko Thank you for the response. Although Love Live does take place in many locations, the 3 places I'm talking about is only located in one place and the two of them are related. I will just ask something like: `What are the places in Love Live that are located in Akihabara?` or `Where could I find Kanda Myoujin Shrine?`, and let the community sort it out.

Comment: You may find it appropriate to split them into several questions to cover what you are looking for, specifying a reduced scope for each.